# Broadband firmware upgrade

Tags: networking, router, firmware

My broadband- MTNL

My ISP- MTNL

When I enter my public ip address in google search, it opens some site after entering default username and password.

When I tried to update my firmware, I got stuck. See image-[firmware upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4cQu.jpg)

Now it ask locations, but I can't select a location. When I click choose file, it opens a dialog box but what file I choose I can't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never update firmware over WiFi. Nor from the upstream network.
Never allow your router to be accessed from the world.

It is **your** router, correct ?

When you downloaded the firmware (!) Where did you save it?

Did you make a backup of your firmware ?  Where did you save that?

The file should have the extension .rom or .bin - if it is compressed you may need to extract it.

It sounds like this question needs a localised answer, you should check forums and your ISP's help pages before coming here.

But seriously, disconnect from the internet first, and use an ethernet cable.

It is almost certainly a Beetel 450tc1, but your ISP may have a *custom* ROM image you may be required to use. This is likely given the custom logo.

Seriously as well, ask your ISP.

Comment: Totally agree with the upstream & wifi firmware update. This is a really easy method to get a permanent paper weight. (Bricksville router) +1

Comment: ISP is bad. Wont tell anything.

Comment: Yes it is my router. Never downloaded firmware before. No backup. How do I update without internet? Site wont open without internet. I dont have ethernet cable. Can I use dongle?

Comment: I dont have any .rom or .bin file in my computer which could be a firmware.

Comment: @suyashsingh234  Then you probably do not need to update at all and you have just landed on the page. Maybe by clicking menu items before rendering had completed. When you type your IP address in, you see what the outside world sees at your IP. You need to close this.  Instead use the local IP of the router, look on the bottom or back of the box. Change the password, disable ping response, disable internet logon. Get a friend to help you. Don't mess with the firmware version at all unless you have been clearly told to.

Comment: ok i was trying to increase my upload speed.